# Firebase database rule to allow retrieval of only some children that have a value in one of their children

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following Firebase database structure:

```
"songs" : { 
  "song1" : {
    "title" : "My song 1",
    "public" : true
  },
  "song2" : {
    "title" : "My song 2",
    "public" : true
  },
  "song3" : {
    "title" : "My song 3",
    "public" : false
  }
}
```

I would like to write a rule that only allow retrieval of nodes that have "true" value under "public". So, the command:

```
firebase.database().ref('songs').once('value')
```

should **only** return:

```
  "song1" : {
    "title" : "My song 1",
    "public" : true
  },
  "song2" : {
    "title" : "My song 2",
    "public" : true
  }
```

and should **not** include song3 in the results (since public is false).

I've tried the rule:

```
"songs" : {
  ".read": "data.child('$songID').child('public').val() == true",
},
```

without success. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found out what I'm trying to do is not possible ([this is the source](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-security-rules-88d94606ce4a)):

> First, the very nature of Firebase demands this kind of behavior. If
>   you query a node in Firebase, you get all of the child nodes. Firebase
>   is so focused on performance that it could never take the time to
>   evaluate rules on all child nodes and potentially delete them from the
>   parent node. It would be an enormous performance hit.

[EDIT]: But see [query-based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules), which may help with a case similar to this one.

Comment: Actually the issue is that security rules are not filters.  The rules will not filter child nodes out of the query. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters

Comment: Thank you. You also pointed me in the direction of using query-based rules.